# is Click at broken on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

On earlier versions of OS X an applescript like :

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
get position of window 1
click at {598, 260}
end tell
```

worked.

But it doesn't work anymore on Mavericks. Is it some kind of broken ?

PS: AppleScript Editor has access to the Accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on Yosemite (tested on Beta 5 and GM).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. There's some discussion [on Apple's site](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24712873).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When I try to run

```
tell application "System Events" to click at {500, 500}
```

it works in a 10.8 VM but results in an error like `System Events got an error: Can’t make {500, 500} into type list` in 10.9.

You can use [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) instead:

```
do shell script "MouseTools -x 500 -y 500;MouseTools -leftClick"
```